# Possible way to collect data from a dropbox folder through vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dropbox, auto-update

My game relies on a resource folder Located in C's Program Files called 'resources' using pretty basic code to make up the front end of the game

```
Public Module getItem
    Public Item = Image.FromFile("C:\Program Files\GameName\resources\ItemName.gif")
End Module
```

to get a picture or video, or text as such I'm pulling the request as such for an update

```
Dim req As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("dropbox link to folder")
Dim res As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

Dim ss As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim version As String = ss.ReadToEnd()
```

so it knows to update but grabbing the entire contents and redownloading it if there's an update in the folder is where im not understanding how i would want to do this in an simple fashion without exhausting memory.

Im familiar with

```
webclient.DownloadFile("database", FolderName)
```

This being a method in which you get a .zip folder, which requires unpacking and locating and replacing files and it just feels inefficient.

But if i only make a few changes is there a way to recognize the change and ONLY download the new images that are needed to that resource file without re-downloading everything (300 MB) or if it need be; to re-download everything (replace i suppose), is there a way to unpack the dropbox folder contents that's online into being a download via just picture into the file? I've given thought to the idea of possibly isolating them to a new folder named 'updated content' that just pulls the new pictures/music/videos out each download. Would that be a viable solution? the idea is to throw the new content in the folder to be read. I can just have the EXE updated and with that comes the new code to pull the new content by X method. Doesn't anyone know of a easier way of possibly doing this, i'd like to stick to Dropbox if at all possible.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Central Notes: 'Dropbox Folder Download'

Comment: One option would be to use a text file to store the latest version number and a list of the updated files.  Upon startup the app downloads the text file and compares it to the current version and if needed downloads the files listed.  This way you can only download the files needed to complete your update.

Comment: That's how i would call the Update() method i have on the loading screen, to prompt the download of the update if new version is available. But going about the downloading process of the new content is where i'm confused, different ways of doing this are what i'm looking for through dropbox, specifically grabbing new content (images) from a folder in the dropbox so only the exe needs to be downloaded, from here it just Downloads the resources(imgs,videos,etc) to the resources folder, but only the NEW content. any ideas?